# show users information with group info joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to show a list of my joomla users, just the name and what group they belong to.

I am able to get the name part ok, but not sure how to get the User group information, some users are part of more than one group. Here is what i sort of want to do.

John is part of Group A, Group B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first get the group ids through the user id and then get the group names through a database query. I use this to get the group names. I modified it so that you can get a result like this `string(44) "Registered,Manager,Administrator,Super Users"`

This is the code I used to get group names for users

```
jimport( 'joomla.access.access' );//Call the Access Class

//Function to get User Groups
function getGroupName($user){
    $groups = JAccess::getGroupsByUser($user, false);
    $groupnames = array();
    foreach ($groups as $gid){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $db->setQuery(
            'SELECT `title`' .
            ' FROM `#__usergroups`' .
            ' WHERE `id` = '. (int) $gid
        );
        $groupnames[] = $db->loadResult();
    }
    return $groupnames;
}
$user_id = 403;//give the user id here
var_dump(implode(",",getGroupName($user_id)));
```

You will get something like this `string(19) "Registered,Manager"`